# How to set tags-table-list as a per-directory local variable?

Tags: directory-local-variables, ctags

I have two tags tables that I would like to be searched/visited when I'm working on one of my R packages. I am able to set them globally with the following code in my `.emacs` config file:

```
(setq tags-table-list '("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/TAGS" "/gitRepos/DADS/TAGS"))
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the equivalent effect by directives placed in the project's `.dir-locals.el`. I've tried each the following (one at a time, of course), and many others, without success:

```
(nil (tags-table-list ("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/"))
((nil (tags-table-list ("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/")))
(nil (tags-table-list ("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/TAGS" "/gitRepos/DADS/TAGS"))
(nil (tags-table-list '("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/"))
(nil (tags-table-list . ('("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/"))))
(nil . ((tags-table-list . (("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/")))))
```

Perhaps relevant is that setting the following variable does work as expected, which makes me suspect that I'm just missing the right incantation for setting `tags-table-list` -- not that the mechanism underlying `.dir-locals.el` is broken:

```
((nil (tags-file-name . "/gitRepos/DADS/TAGS")))
```

How can I set the value of `tags-table-list` using the notation required by `.dir-locals.el`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your attempts to set `tags-table-list` are errorneous.

All cases except the second one do not define a mapping of modes to alists of settings and are therefore wrong.

Only the second case remains to be discussed. In the following I add the missing closing parenthesis `)`:

```
((nil (tags-table-list ("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/"))))
```

Nevertheless, also this setting for `tags-table-list` is wrong. The elements of the alist mapping variables to values are cons, so it is better to write the setting using dotted-pair notation:

```
((nil (tags-table-list . (("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/")))))
```

This shows that you assign a list of a list to `tags-table-list`. But you should assign a list of directory names. One simple solution is adding a dot behind `tags-table-list`:

```
((nil (tags-table-list . ("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/"))))
```

I have just tested it with

`emacs-version`: `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-04-12`

Contents of file `~/tmp/.dir-locals.el`:

```
((nil (tags-table-list . ("~/tmp/DADS/"))))
```

Contents of file `~/tmp/DADS//TAGS`:

```
^L
../test/test.c,14
int main(^?1,0
```

Contents of file `~/tmp/test/test.c`:

```c
int main() {
    return 0; /* \f$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\f$. */
}
```

The command `tags-search` called with interactive argument `main` works like expected when the buffer for file `~/tmp/test/test.c` is active and point is at the start of that file. It places point at the end of `main` in file `~/tmp/test/test.c`.

Comment: Personally I would recommend using dotted-pair notation for the (MODE . ALIST) pairs as well.

Comment: @phils Yes, you are perfectly right. But, I wanted to do a **minimal edit** indicating the OP his error. The first omitted dot did not induce the problem. So a discussion about that other dot is more a comment than an answer. I am actually happy that you addressed this topic in a comment;-).

Comment: @phils By that do you mean that you would recommend (in my case) writing `((nil . ((tags-table-list . ("/R/Source/R-devel-SVN/" "/gitRepos/DADS/")))))` ?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Thanks, Tobias, for your answer. Really appreciate your taking the time to explain it as well.